# How to pass float argv parameters to another script?

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to run a simple script named `test` using `python test` in the terminal in order to call two other scripts.

This is the script I am running

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import rospy
import subprocess
import time

from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from std_msgs.msg import Empty

subprocess.call("./takeoff_sim")

time.sleep(2)

subprocess.call("./forward_sim" + sys.argv[5.0] + sys.argv[2.0])
```

But I am getting the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test", line 15, in <module>
    subprocess.call(["./forward_sim"] + sys.argv[5.0] + sys.argv[2.0])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float
```

In this case both arguments need to a float thus, I cant just change them to int `0.5` should be the first argument and `2.0` the second one. Here is the `forward_sim` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

def commander(speed, time):
    movement_publisher = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel', Twist , queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node("bebop_commander") #Use log_level=rospy.DEBUG to see debug messages
    rate = rospy.Rate(20) # 20hz
    counter = 0.0
    movement_cmd = Twist()

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        movement_cmd.linear.x = speed
        movement_cmd.linear.y = 0
        movement_cmd.linear.z = 0
        movement_cmd.angular.x = 0
        movement_cmd.angular.y = 0
        movement_cmd.angular.z = 0
        rospy.logdebug("Publishing")
    counter += 0.05
        movement_publisher.publish(movement_cmd)
        rate.sleep()
        if counter >= time:
        break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    speed = float(sys.argv[0])
    time = float(sys.argv[1])


rospy.logdebug("Adelante") # Use rospy.logdebug() for debug messages.
print("Adelante")

if speed > 0:
        rospy.logdebug("Velocidad = %s m/s", speed)
    print("Velocidad =",speed," m/s",)
else:
        raise ValueError("Falta parametro de velocidad o el valor es incorrecto")

if time > 0 :
        rospy.logdebug("Tiempo = %s s", time)
    print("Tiempo =" ,time, " s")
else:
        raise ValueError("Falta parametro de tiempo o el valor es incorrecto")

try:
    commander(speed, time)
except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
    pass
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `1:0.5` and `2:2.0`?

Comment: you don't need `sys.argv`. You need strings with float numbers `["./forward_sim", "0.5", "2.0"]`.  Or sometimes one string with spaces `"./forward_sim 0.5 2.0"`.

Comment: FWIW, `sys.argv` is a list, so its elements in it are referenced using integers inside `[]` characters (aka indexing). i.e. `sys.argv[0]` is the script name, `sys.argv[1]` is its first argument, etc.

Comment: argv elements are **always** strings -- at the operating system level, they can't be anything else. Whether that string encodes to or decodes from a floating point number is almost irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys.argv` is only for *receiving* arguments. To pass values as arguments to another script, you need only convert them to strings and add them directly to the command line.

```
subprocess.call(["./forward_sim", str(5.0), str(2.0)])
```

When the other script receives them, it needs to convert each string back to a float:

```
# This is forward_sim

arg1 = float(sys.argv[1])
arg2 = float(sys.argv[2])
```

Note that `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script itself, not the first argument.

Comment: Hijacking this. Is there a way to pass floats to an nargs (list) cmd line argument with subprocess? For example  -float '5.0 2.0'.
 
Python argparse cannot convert this string to two floats. @chepner